# Strange behaviour of Cube effect on Ubuntu 16.04 Flashback - Gnome

Tags: drivers, nvidia, 16.04, gnome, compiz

After installing Flash-back Gnome on a Ubuntu 16.04, Compiz, and configuring graphics via gnome-control-center, and finally activating the cube effects, this is what I get when rotating the cube with zoom effect.

I'm not worried about it from a "visual" point of view; I just want the cube for its operational advantages, just wondering whether it could be a symptom of more serious problems.

**Hardware:** Nvidia GeForce GT 640, 3 monitors.

**Driver:** X.Org X server driver.

**Configuration of the cube:** 4 sides, 3 displays on each one of them.

Output of **/usr/lib/nux/unity_support_test -p**:

```
user_@user_-desktop:~$ /usr/lib/nux/unity_support_test -pOpenGL
vendor string:   nouveau
OpenGL renderer string: Gallium 0.4 on NVE7
OpenGL version string:  3.0 Mesa 11.2.0

Not software rendered:    yes
Not blacklisted:          yes
GLX fbconfig:             yes
GLX texture from pixmap:  yes
GL npot or rect textures: yes
GL vertex program:        yes
GL fragment program:      yes
GL vertex buffer object:  yes
GL framebuffer object:    yes
GL version is 1.4+:       yes

Unity 3D supported:       yes
user_@user_-desktop:~$
```

Everything seems to be ok, but I get this kind of "abstract/deconstructed" cube:

[image]

What do you people think about it? Just a lesser visual problem?

Comment: What was abnormal on that screenshot?

Comment: Normally the cube has (numer of screens * number of desktops), but this cube is showing all three screens as 1; it should have 12 sides, not 4.  To me it's abnormal since I've been using compiz's cube for more than 6 years and it never behaved this way. Perhaps it's miscalculating the size of each side... not sure about the real problem